# shadow of an object in a shader real-time?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

how do I use the shadow of an object in a real-time shader?
both the shadow itself and the drop shadow?

to render on eevee ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get a 'drop shadow effect', you can enable and configure Ambient Occlusion in your render settings.

For fuuther control, the `Shader to RGB` node will allow you to use the brightness of each texel as an input value for your shader magic.

If you want to customize the shadow cast *by* your Object on other objects, then you'll have to edit the materials for your other objects. You won't be able to differentiate which object cast this shadow without doing some very complicated view layer separation.

If you want to customize the shadow cast *onto* your Object, simply connect a 100% white `Diffuse BSDF` into a `Shader to RGB`. This will give you a mask of all the shadows and self shadows (incidence darkening)

Comment: Do you know how I can make a shader like the image below?

https://i.pinimg.com/564x/15/bd/95/15bd95c006498d8ba1e4c9c761c35c47.jpg

Comment: This 'drop shadow' that you're seeing is Ambient Occlusion. Enable it in your render settings